# как продолжить родительский цикл while python?

Tags: python, циклы, while

```
while True:(1 цикл)
    что-нибудь
    while True:(2 цикл)
        if a == 1:
            continue(это)
```

как сделать, чтобы этот continue запускал цикл 1 с начала, а не цикл 2? Помогите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 3):

Просто вместо `continue` используйте `break`.

В более сложных случаях, с несколькими уровнями вложенности, когда надо прервать сразу два-три уровня циклов, хорошим решением станет вынос нескольких внутренних уровней циклов в функцию и её прерывание с помощью `return`